# Отловить исключение в динамически подгружаемой сборке

Tags: c#

Есть простое приложение на C# в котором одна Assembly подгружается динамически :

```
       var all = File.ReadAllBytes("path to file");
       var a = Assembly.Load(all);
       object o = a.CreateInstance("namespace.class");
       Type t = a.GetType("namespace.class");
       var mi = t.GetMethod("MethodName");
       mi.Invoke(o, null);
```

Как отловить и обработать исключение при вызове `mi.Invoke(o, null)` когда таковые возникают ? Просто обернуть в `try{}catch()` не подходит.

UPD По совету уважаемого @VlaD порылся в стеке и обнаружил следующее :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2 В стеке вызова, если `показать внешний код` :

> [Переход от управляемого кода к машинному]
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner, string text, string caption, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons buttons, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon icon, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions options, bool showHelp)    Нет данных
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string text, string caption)  Нет данных
>       CompilerScrupt!KovalZadania.Program.Start() Нет данных
>       [Переход от машинного кода к управляемому]
>       [Переход от управляемого кода к машинному]
>     CGAAF.exe!Custodian.MainWindow.StartQute()Строка 158    C#
>       CGAAF.exe!Custodian.MainWindow.enterClient_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)Строка 98  C#
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)  Нет данных
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()   Нет данных
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()  Нет данных
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)  Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, System.Windows.RoutedEvent newEvent)  Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)    Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input)  Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport)   Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel)   Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)   Нет данных
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)    Нет данных
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Нет данных
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Нет данных
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Нет данных
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Нет данных
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Нет данных
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Нет данных
>       [Переход от машинного кода к управляемому]
>       [Переход от управляемого кода к машинному]
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Нет данных
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Нет данных
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Нет данных
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Нет данных
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Нет данных
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()  Нет данных
>       CGAAF.exe!WpfApp2.App.Main()    Нет данных

Comment: @Сергей: Нажмите правой кнопкой на [External Code] и выберите в меню «Show External Code». (Или как оно там на русском.) Там, внизу, в «Стеке Вызовов».

Comment: @VladD очень много выдал

Comment: @Сергей: Очень хорошо, давайте это в вопрос.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66067/discussion-on-question-by------).

Comment: @VladD вам давно подвезли стектрейс )

Comment: @Nofate: Спасибо!

Comment: @Сергей: Окей, тогда вопрос, что за исключение? Код висит в месседжбоксе. Может быть, вы вызываете код WinForms, но не инициализировали WinForms-приложение?